# Run a calculation on each row in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have what is probably a really simple question. I know what I want to do, I just don't know how to "ask" VBA to do what I want.

I have a data set that is pulled from another location periodically. Within this data set I need to have a calculation run using 2 of the cells (columns b and c) for each row where d= the value in column b and WFS= the value in column c. Pi is a defined variable set at 3.14159265

```
WFS * 60 * (Pi * (d * d / 4)) * 0.284
```

The output for each calculation from B and C will be output in the same row in column E.

The data set is constantly growing and can be filtered so I need to identify the last row and to only perform the calculations on the visible rows. There are already some other nonrelevant lines in the script that are omitted below.

```
Sub Calculate_Average_Deposition_Rate()
    
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowTracker As Long
    Dim Dia As Long, WFS As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim num As Double
    
    'Change Screen Updating, Set Active Sheet, Find LastRow
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    Worksheets("2023").Activate
    LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Define Variables
    Set ws = Worksheets("2023")
    Pi = 3.14159265358979

'OMMITED NONRELEVANT LINES ARE HERE

    'Clear Output Column
        ws.Range("E6:H" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    
    'Calculate the Deposition Rate In Each Visible Row
        Set rng3 = Range("B6:C" & LastRow).SpecialCellsCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work:

```
Set rng3 = ws.Range("E6:E" & LastRow).SpecialCellsCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rng3.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2] * 60 * (PI() * (RC[-3] * RC[-3] / 4)) * 0.284"
```

Comment: This was nearly perfect. I had an error in the Set rng3 line, and the Pi variable doesn't work in the formulaR1C1 function, so I just had to replace with the actual value.

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot about the Pi...   Fixed above using the `PI()` worksheet function.